# RegEx to match a string if it does not follow another string

Tags: regex

What RegEx pattern should be used to match `CP_` but not `CPLAT::CP_`?

Comment: Being able to read and compose RegEx take practice, just because you know one language, doesn't automatically mean you can pick up another one with no effort, especially one that uses a distinctly different idiom. e.g. try Lisp. - It's not that RegEx is particularly hard, it's just not all that accessible, I'd recommend you use some tools that allow regex as search patterns, and do them as often as possible, a little practice goes a long way.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<!CPLAT::)CP_
```

Uses [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
[^:]CP_
```

Will find all instances of `CP_` that aren't preceeded by a `:`

use the `g` option (depending on regex flavor) if you expect more than one `CP_` match per line.

Comment: The `g` flag is required by some flavors, like Perl and JavaScript, if you're searching for more than one match--same line or separate lines, it doesn't matter.  The `m` modifier is completely unrelated; all it does is change the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: My mistake, I thought `m` was the equivalent of `g` on some flavours.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, does anyone have a very simple tutorial like RegEx for Dummies? Is it strange that I code in C++ but cannot grasp RegEx easily?

No, it's not strange.  Regex mastery requires a certain mindset that doesn't come naturally.  And being able to program, in C++ or any other language, doesn't seem to help--if anything, it's a handicap.  There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), but even the best tutorial will only get you to a pidgin level.  If you really want to get your head around regexes, you need [The Book](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/regex3/index.html).

Another problem is that there's no standard for regexes; every programming language, every framework, every IDE or text editor seems to have its own "flavor" of regex.  Some have features that others don't, while some use different syntax to do the same things.  That's where [The Other Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689) comes in.  Many examples of the kinds of tasks we commonly use regexes for, in several of the most popular flavors, and thoroughly explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want "^CP_" as your regular expression. The ^ tells the expression to check to this patter at the start of the input.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: ^ anchors to the first character in the string/line, not the first character in the word/symbol.   Sounds like the OP was needing to search across files, not just compare a single word in a string.

Comment: @corey - yup search across files